# Brightness control

Tags: brightness, asus

I am using Asus ROG laptop with ubuntu installed, I am not able to change my brightness from keyboard(fn+down arrow).However I have option to change from the GUI.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken already a look on this topic:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049681/ubuntu-18-04-cannot-change-display-brightness-or-wake-from-sleep-on-asus-rog-lap
?

Generally adding the parameter acpi_backlight=vendor to GRUB and then loading the Asus Notebook WMI module.